# Javascript / ajax code - works in chrome and firefox but not in IE10

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

What I'm trying to do is limit the options of one select box based on what the user chooses in a prior select box.  It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 10 the only thing that shows up is the text "Not Found".  I'm not sure, but my guess is that something is going wrong in request.status.  What it is, however, I have no idea.

```
function prepForms() {
for (var i = 0; i<document.forms.length; i++) {
    var thisform = document.forms[i];
    var departCity = document.getElementById("departcity");
    departCity.onchange = function() {
        var new_content = document.getElementById("ajaxArrive");
        if (submitFormWithAjax(thisform, new_content)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
}

function getHTTPObject() {
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined")
    XMLHttpRequest = function() {
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
            catch (e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
            catch (e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
            catch (e) {}
        return false;
    }
return new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function submitFormWithAjax(whichform, thetarget) {
var request = getHTTPObject();
if (!request) {return false;}
var dataParts = [];
var element;
for (var i = 0; i<whichform.elements.length; i++) {
    element = whichform.elements[i];
    dataParts[i] = element.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(element.value);
}
var data = dataParts.join("&");
request.open("POST", "flightlocationfilter.asp#ajaxArrive", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            var matches = request.responseText.match(/<div id="ajaxArrive">([\s\S]+)<\/div>/);
            if (matches.length > 0) {
                thetarget.innerHTML = matches[1];
            } else {
                thetarget.innerHTML = "<p>--Error--</p>";
            }
        } else {
            thetarget.innerHTML = "<p>" + request.statusText + "</p>";
        }
    }
};
request.send(data);
return true;
};
```

Edit: After walking through with the IE Developer Tools, it looks like the request.readyState is not moving beyond 1 to 4.

Comment: +1 for recording me pure JS ajax, without jQuery.

Comment: Did you checked the request on Newtwork Dev Tools tab? What happens with that request? That prefligh requests sucks. Maybe IE is blocking it for some security setting.

Comment: are you sure that ie10 is not caching a old version of your script..

Comment: While it may or may not be relevant, you should remove "#ajaxArrive" from your request URL. The URL fragment is never sent to the server and shouldn't be present in the XHR URL.

Comment: EricLaw - that turned out to be exactly the problem.  Thank you!